# I want to send reminder before particular time in java

Tags: scheduler, email-notifications, mail-sender, java-calendar

I have calendar events in my java web project, 
in which i want to send reminder before some time (time can be minutes/hours/second depends on selection while creating event), 
How can i send mails before those particular time?

Comment: Run a cron job which reads the calendar events and sends reminder emails before the configured amount of time than the event time.

Comment: That’s a lot of questions in one and no effort shown. Please separate your questions. And please for each question show us what you have found in your search and what you have tried. We can guide you much better from there. As your question stands, it is completely unsuited for the StackOverflow format. You may want to study [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) more closely.